# Is there an analog of "cde" that works on microsoft windows?

Tags: linux, windows, r, parallel-processing

So there is a packager on linux called "cde". ([link](http://www.pgbovine.net/cde.html))

It works with things like [OpenMOLE](http://www.openmole.org/) to allow wrapping executables like Java, C++, or R into a single framework for parallel execution.

Sadly, most of the non-IT business infrastructure is Microsoft Windows based.

What are my options for detection and wrapping executables (like R, or whatever) without having to go into very elaborate (Rcpp craziness) to make it work on windows?  Is there a "cde" for windows?  If so what is it, where do I learn more about it, and what are its strengths and weaknesses?

Answer (score 0):

I looked everywhere.  It does not exist.